# Creating a TCP Client Connection with SSL

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, tcp

I'm trying to create a TCP connection and send/read data that uses SSL, but I haven't been able to successfully accomplish this.

What I'd like to do is something like this:

```
    TcpClient _tcpClient = new TcpClient("host", 110);

    BinaryReader reader = 
       new BinaryReader(new System.Net.Security.SslStream(_tcpClient.GetStream(), true));

    Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadString());
```

I haven't had any luck with it though. An exception is thrown when creating the BinaryReader.

Does anyone know of a simple example that does this? I'm not interested in writing the server side of this, just the client.

Comment: BinaryReder reads primitive data types as binary values in a specific encoding, is that what your server sends?

Comment: Please post the exception text.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

BinaryReader reads primitive data types as binary values in a specific encoding, is that what your server sends?
If not use StreamReader:

```
TcpClient _tcpClient = new TcpClient("host", 110);

StreamReader reader = 
   new StreamReader(new System.Net.Security.SslStream(_tcpClient.GetStream(), true));

Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure if this will work for your application but I would recommend taking a look at stunnel:
http://www.stunnel.org

I've used it for wrapping existing TCP connections in the past.