# How to send\recive SslStream from TCP server in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, ssl, tcp

How to send\recive SslStream from TCP server in C#? I need a simple tutorial on baciks of TCP stream protection using Sockets, SSLStreams and simple TCP listrning server... Is there any such tutorial? Please, help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a TCP Client Connection with SSL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252365/creating-a-tcp-client-connection-with-ssl)

Comment: The question you linked to is about a *client*, this one is about a *server*, so not sure how this could possibly be seen as a duplicate...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Doesn't the MSDN help for SslStream include examples?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream.aspx

Comment: there is no complete example for async.

Comment: @virtouso Yeh the docs could do with some more modern examples.

Comment: can you help me with it? its my question link. im waiting to put a bounty on it. i really looking for a good answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28552905/how-to-make-asynchron-multiclient-server-with-ssl