# Determine the SSL connection type when connecting through TCP

Tags: c#, ssl, tcp

I am connecting to a host using the following code:

```
protected bool OpenSocket(string hostIPAddress, int hostIPPort)
{
    try
    {
        if ((this._tcpSocket != null) && (this._tcpSocket.Connected == true))
            return (true);
    }
    catch { }

    // Reset variables
    this._isSocketOpen = false;
    this._isSSLOpen = false;

    string ipAddress = this.GetHostIPAddress(hostIPAddress);
    this._tcpSocket = new TcpClient(ipAddress, hostIPPort);
    this._tcpipConnectionStream = this._tcpSocket.GetStream();
    this._isSocketOpen = true;
    return true;
}
```

Is there any way to determine the SSL connection type (i.e. SSL2, SSL3, TL1.2) when connecting to the host? I've looked into using something like this:

```
SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(this._tcpSocket.GetStream(), false, new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate), null);
sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(hostIPAddress);
```

However I think that would be for setting the SSL protocol wouldn't it, rather than obtaining it? I am rather lost.

Comment: the code which you posted is enough to create the SSL connection to the host? is this what you are looking for, or I miss understood you

Comment: see also this link it may be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252365/

Comment: @Hakem Fostok. I just want to know what the connection type was after the connection has been established

Answer (score 0):

You can check the type of the connection by querying the `SslProtocol` property of the `SslStream` type.

```
SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(this._tcpSocket.GetStream(), false, new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate), null);
sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(hostIPAddress);
Console.WriteLine(sslStream.SslProtocol);
```

This property will return a value from of the Enumeration 
[SslProtocols](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.authentication.sslprotocols(v=vs.110).aspx)

for more information about this property, see the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream.sslprotocol(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thank you! I kept on getting an exception when querying the ssl protocol when I tried using that code before. I have no idea why it's now working!

Comment: But just hold on one moment. By instantiating the sslStream variable it's not setting the SSL protocol in the code somehow is it, automatically? I am not sure how it all works. What determines the SSL protocol? I ran the code and got a value of TLS but I am worried that this was just the default value and it's being set by my code rather than being obtained by my code.

Comment: No this is not the default value, Please notice that the `SslProtocol` property has no set property, it is just a get property (readonly property) and the SslStream will set the value for you, so you can query it.

Comment: also if you notice the first link in my answer, you can go to MSDN and see that the `TLS` value is not the default value for this enumeration, so do not worry at all about this point.

Comment: in that link also you can see a good example of using SslStream. I hope that this is helpful

Comment: You are welcome. if this answer solve your problem, please make sure to mark this answer as accepted answer, this will be helpful for people who has the same question of your.

Comment: Unfortunately I keep getting the following error: Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream. What does that mean?

Comment: what is the type of the exception ? if you can please updated your question to include all the information about the Exception (its type and message) and in what is the line that you receive this exception in. If your code has been changed please also put your new code in the updated questions. and I will help as I can